# Why do I get: "Error: cannot find module sass" when I run "gulp" in terminal?

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to run a *gulp task* but when I go to `Terminal > Run Task... > gulp` it says `No gulp task found`. I run `gulp` in the terminal and I get the title's error.

---

`which sass`: `/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/sass`.

`which node`: `/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/node`.

`which gulp`: `/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/gulp`.

Gulp version:

```
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

Gulp sass version: `^5.1.0`.

My `gulpfile.js`; *is* in the root folder (as my `styles.scss`, `styles.css`, `styles.min.css`, `package.json`, `package-lock.json` and `node_modules/`), with the code:

```
// Sass configuration
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

gulp.task('sass', function(cb) {
  gulp
    .src('*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(
      gulp.dest(function(f) {
        return f.base;
      })
    );
  cb();
});

gulp.task(
  'default',
  gulp.series('sass', function(cb) {
    gulp.watch('*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
    cb();
  })
);
```

---

I removed and re-installed `gulp` and `gulp-sass` but the result is the same.

I'm following [these steps](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css#_step-1-install-gulp-and-some-plugins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding `npm i --save-dev sass`.